# PushPopupPageAsync not found in Xamarin Forms Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Not found  PushPopupPageAsync

```
_navigationService.PushPopupPageAsync( "MyPopupPage" );
```

I am using Rg.Plugin.Popup along withg Prism
but PushPopupPageAsync not available on INavigationService

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you should be calling `PushPopupPageAsync`? Rg.Plugin.Popup extends the Navigation service with `PushPopupAsync` - note there is no *Page* in the name.

To be able to use `PushPopupAsync` you also need to have:

`using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Extensions;`

in the source file where you want to call `PushPopupAsync`

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use the [Prism.Plugin.Popups](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Plugin.Popups/) made by the Prism maintainer, then you can just use the standard NavigateAsync method:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("MyPopupPage")
```

With this, te page is pushed as a popup with Rg.Plugin.Popup. (of course you have to target a PopupPage to make this works)